# Modal not working with cookie set in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cookies, syntax, colorbox

I'm using the Colorbox modal pop-up throughout a website, but I want to prevent it from appearing in the following conditions are met:

1. The modal has already appeared once in the last 15 days or
2. The visitor enters the website through a specific page and
3. The visitor visits any other page on the site after viewing specific page

The following code seems to work OK with I test it in everything except IE8 & 9. I can get the modal to open one time in IE but not again, not even when cache/cookies are cleared and browser is restarted.  I don't see any errors in the console.  Can anyone help me?

My idea is to show the modal when someone enters the site except if a specified DIV is present on the page or if they have already viewed that page with the DIV.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var jQuery_1_8_3 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
            jQuery_1_8_3(document).ready(function(){
                    var emailFormExists = jQuery_1_8_3('#e2ma_signup_form');
                    if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1 && !(emailFormExists.length)){
                        var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;
                        var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
                        document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
                        jQuery_1_8_3.colorbox({width:"30%", inline:true, href:"#email"});
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    jQuery_1_8_3('#e2ma_signup_form').length
                        var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;
                        var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
                        document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();  
                    }
                });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was - IE has a setting at the top of the "Delete Browsing History" menu that says "Preserve Favorites Website Data".  This box was checked, and when I pulled up the window I just quickly scanned to be sure the cookies option was checked without reading everything else.

I had been using the Cache > Clear Cookies For Domain option in the developer tools to clear the cookies when testing, but I don't think it was working since that option was checked in the browsing history menu and the page I am testing is bookmarked in my favorites.

Feel kinda like a dumbass not having caught that before but maybe I'm not the only one and this can help someone down the road.